# Specify dbus session address on windows

Tags: windows, dbus

The default session.conf for DBus on Windows (https://code.google.com/p/dbus-windows-installer/downloads/list) uses `<listen>autolaunch:scope=install-path</listen>` which, as the name implies, uses the current path of the dbus-daemon executable to somehow determine the session address.

Is there a way to specify an explicit path instead? perhaps something with `tcp:`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After many attempts, I have found the solution. Even though the 1.4.3 version of DBus for Windows that is (at least for now) available at https://code.google.com/p/dbus-windows-installer/downloads/list is quite old, it does in fact support `tcp:` syntax.

Installing `DBus-Windows-Installer-1.4.1-2.exe` does two things:

1. It delivers the DBus libraries and default configuration in `C:\Program Files (x86)\DBus`
2. It adds `C:\Program Files (x86)\DBus\bin` to the `%PATH%`

Having the latter is necessary so that your application can access DBus DLLs and EXEs at runtime. To make this installation use the `tcp:` syntax, you have to

1. Edit `C:\Program Files (x86)\DBus\etc\session.conf` to `<listen>tcp:host=localhost,port=54321,family=ipv4</listen>`
2. Edit `C:\Program Files (x86)\DBus\bin\dbus-env.bat` to `set DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS=tcp:host=localhost,port=54321,family=ipv4`
3. Launch the session daemon from an environment that first executes `dbus-env.bat` and then run `dbus-daemon.exe --session`
4. (Optional) Launch the session monitor from an environment that first executes `dbus-env.bat` and then run `dbus-monitor.exe --session`
5. Launch your application from an environment that first executes `dbus-env.bat` and then actually runs your application

As I said above, DBus 1.4.3 is quite old. In fact, according to https://code.google.com/p/support/wiki/ReadOnlyTransition it might not even be available for download soon. At the time of this writing, the latest stable branch is 1.10. So, here are the instructions for building your own latest DBus

1. Install Visual Studio

   - Any version 2010 and later should suffice, including the free Express versions
2. Install CMake

   - I believe any recent version will do, but I used https://cmake.org/files/v3.4/cmake-3.4.1-win32-x86.exe
   - My recommendation is to NOT add cmake to path, just to keep your system clean
3. Get libexpat

   - I believe any recent version will do, but I used http://olex.openlogic.com/package_versions/6311/download?package_version_id=1765&path=https%3A%2F%2Folex-secure.openlogic.com%2Fcontent%2Fopenlogic%2Fexpat%2F2.0.1%2Fopenlogic-expat-2.0.1-windows-bin-1.zip
   - run the executable from the zipfile, which installs libexpat into C:\Program Files (x86)\Expat 2.0.1 directory.

     - Let's call this ${expatDir}
4. Get the DBus source

   - git clone git://anongit.freedesktop.org/git/dbus/dbus
   - cd dbus

     - Let's call this ${dbusSrcDir}
   - git checkout dbus-1.10

     - this is the current stable branch
5. Start Developer Command Prompt for VS2015

   - cd ${dbusSrcDir}
   - cd ..
   - mkdir dbus-build
   - cd dbus-build
   - "c:\Program Files (x86)\CMake\bin\cmake.exe" -G "NMake Makefiles" -DCMAKE_INCLUDE_PATH:PATH="${expatDir}\Source\lib" -DCMAKE_LIBRARY_PATH:PATH="${expatDir}\Bin" -DDBUS_BUILD_TESTS:BOOL=OFF -DDBUS_DISABLE_ASSERT:BOOL=ON -DDBUS_USE_OUTPUT_DEBUG_STRING:BOOL=ON -DDBUS_ENABLE_DOXYGEN_DOCS:BOOL=OFF ..\dbus\cmake
   - nmake
6. At this point, you can either do `nmake install` to install to `C:\Program Files (x86)\DBus` or you can make a distributable "deploy package" by

   - mkdir c:\temp\dbus-deploy
   - mkdir c:\temp\dbus-deploy\bin
   - mkdir c:\temp\dbus-deploy\share
   - mkdir c:\temp\dbus-deploy\share\dbus-1
   - copy bin\dbus-1-3.dll c:\temp\dbus-deploy\bin
   - copy bin\dbus-daemon.exe c:\temp\dbus-deploy\bin
   - copy bin\dbus-env.bat c:\temp\dbus-deploy\bin
   - copy bin\dbus-launch.exe c:\temp\dbus-deploy\bin
   - copy bin\dbus-monitor.exe c:\temp\dbus-deploy\bin
   - copy bin\dbus-send.exe c:\temp\dbus-deploy\bin
   - copy ${expatDir}\Bin\libexpat.dll c:\temp\dbus-deploy\bin
   - Create a c:\temp\dbus-deploy\share\dbus-1\session.conf with the usual contents which includes `<listen>tcp:host=localhost,port=54321,family=ipv4</listen>`
   - Edit `c:\temp\dbus-deploy\bin\dbus-env.bat` to `set DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS=tcp:host=localhost,port=54321,family=ipv4`
7. To use "the deploy package" in your application, modify %PATH% to point to your "deploy package" bin directory and make sure to source dbus-env.bat before doing anything.