# How to run dbus-daemon on windows?

Tags: c++, windows, qt, dbus, qtdbus

I'm  trying  to run a Qt d-bus example (chat) on Windows. It compiles fine but I get this error:

> Cannot connect to the D-Bus session bus. Please check your system
> settings and try again. QEventDispatcherWin32::wakeUp: Failed to post
> a message

I installed D-Bus on Windows through a ready made [installer](https://code.google.com/archive/p/dbus-windows-installer/downloads) found in Google archives.

Can someone give me an idea how to run dbus-daemon on Windows?

Comment: Have you reviewed [this question (and answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34342061/2167797) to see if it might provide information that would help?

Comment: @thank you for your answers, yes i reviewed it, but i still can't set up it under my Machine, i obtain this error 

C:\Windows\system32>dbus-monitor.exe
Failed to open connection to session bus: Failed to get auto launch address from launched dbus-daemon

C:\Windows\system32>dbus-monitor.exe
Failed to open connection to session bus: Failed to get auto launch address from launched dbus-daemon

C:\Windows\system32>